# SWRevealViewcontroller UIbutton action first click not working, after that its working fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have done some demo project for the side menu.in that i have 3 vc. i am using right side menu to show the side menu view. Here, from vc1 to vc 2 push. And in vc2 i have one button to open right side menu. But here, when i click first time its not working. After second click its not working.

Sam if i go back and come again. First click its not working. After second click its working fine. Any idea why its happening ?.

My demo project : [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vF7aiB4BkCSk43P9SxnOcuKJTMB_crgd/view?usp=sharing)

I added uibutton action like below.

// from v1 to v3 vc

```
- (IBAction)tap:(id)sender {
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    VC3 * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

to show menu :

```
- (IBAction)DASD:(id)sender {
     [self.btn addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you button target action in `ViewDidLoad`. Don't create an `ibAction` to trigger the side menu.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.yourButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have checked your code. you have to do just one change.

`[self.btn addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

remove above code from the `- (IBAction)DASD:(id)sender` and add in `viewDidLoad` Method of `VC3.m` file.

so your code of `VC3.m` file is looks like below way :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.btn addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)DASD:(id)sender {}
```

Comment: @david is it works for you ? if not then let me know.